# How do you challenge a ruling?

Tags: discussion, support

I recently had a question closed as an exact duplicate. It was not an exact duplicate.

My question: [How can I edit GTK+3 themes (preferably with a GUI)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68861/how-can-i-customize-my-themes-in-ubuntu-11-10)

The other question: [How do I change to a theme not listed in the Appearance screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61567/how-do-i-change-the-theme)

I was asking how I could change things within a theme. The other question is asking how to change from one theme to another theme.

Now, I looked around the area where it marked my question as closed... And there was no link to say, "no, this shouldn't have been closed!" I left a comment on my thread, but that didn't seem to work. Two days later, I looked to message the two people who closed the thread, but could not reach them. So I was, in a nutshell, shocked to find that there *does not seem to be any recourse available to me.*

Is my question merely to be forgotten forever?

Comment: You've done the right thing posting here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is not forgotten! One of the great things about this site is most everything is reversible. Mistake can be made from time to time and we like to correct those as quickly as possible.

In general, if your question was closed as a duplicate, too localized, or non-constructive it's likely because it's too difficult to discern a difference from those mentioned. Consider editing your question to make it's scope more obvious, clearly state the goals of your, what you've tried if anything, links to places you've already researched, etc. The more information you pack into the question the better we can gear an answer for you.

In your example you exclaim how your themes have gone away, how you dislike the defaults and wish to change. Your second post goes on to say customizing themes but that can be construed in multiple meanings. In this case you'll likely want to capitalize more on the fact you wish to either create or modify current theme aesthetics.

Once you've reviewed your question, made any applicable changes, there area few ways to get it reopened. If you have enough reputation you can vote to reopen the question. If not, you can flag the question using the "flag" button with an appeal to re-open your question. From there a moderator will review your question and either reopen it or leave a note as to why it will not be.

If you disagree with any of this during this process you can always post on the [meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com) (as you have) asking why and here you'll be able to carry out a discussion in more detail as to why something was closed.

Comment: Huh -- so there is a reopen link there. it would have been nice if that was visible in the shiny box telling me my question was closed.

Comment: @Daniel It's only available if you have [enough reputation](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/close-questions), otherwise you'll have to just flag for moderator attention.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi It would be nice though to notify users of the possibility of flagging the question after editing, in the 'marked as a duplicate by...'-box.